# Paypal with Debit Card Number shows invalid card number

Tags: asp.net, paypal

i am using paypal on my asp.net application. When i write sample credit card numbers it works fine but for debit card sample it always shows invalid card number. Do i need to set some extra settings?

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified each type of card by like this 
`<asp:listitem value="Visa" text="Visa" selected="True">
<asp:listitem value="MASTERCARD" text="MASTERCARD">
<asp:listitem value="AMERICAN EXPRESS" text="AMERICAN EXPRESS">`

The link below gives some more clarity on intergrating paypal into your asp.net application. https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/501447/Howplustoplusintegratepluspaypalpluscreditpluscard

Comment: thank you for response. It actually works fine for all of them but only for credit cards numbers when i try sample debit card it gives error.